# How do you use RxScala in Intellij Idea 14?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, reactive-programming, intellij-14, rx-scala

I've just recently started coding in Scala and I want to start working with RxScala but I haven't been able to figure out how to import it into Intellij. Does anyone know how to do this, I've spent the last few hours trying to figure this out and I'm no closer than when I started? Also I'm using Ubuntu if that effects anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/index.html). IDEA automatically recognizes and imports SBT projects. You just need to create a basic `build.sbt` file in the root folder containing

```
name := "your project"

organization := "your organization"

version := "x.y.z"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "io.reactivex" %% "rxscala" % "0.25.0" // or whatever version you want to use
```

and "Open project" in IDEA.

Comment: Definitely the simplest way to go. Plus you can easily share your project with people who use other IDEs or no IDE at all.

Comment: Suggested edit for this answer: You might have to install the SBT plugin in Intellij if it's not yet installed.

Comment: @SamuelGruetter SBT support is included in the Scala plugin since IDEA 13 http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/